# Refresh actionbar item icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This works just fine but If I'm on a different activity and I use the back button, it won't update the action bar because the activity is already created and it won't update the action bar. Already tried to use  supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() on the on_create method but it didn't work.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    Cursor cursor = messages.getMessages();
    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar1, menu);
    }else{
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar2, menu);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: `InvalidateOptionsMenu()` will call onPrepareOptionsMenu and not onCreateOptionsMenu. Make sure you override/code that method too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation for [onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) states:

> This is only called once, the first time the options menu is
>   displayed. To update the menu every time it is displayed, see
>   onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu).

So going back to an already created Activity does not trigger `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu)` again.
What I suggest you to do is create just one menu containing all the menu items and selectively activate/deactivate them in `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)` based on one or more flags. Then put `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in `onResume()` which is called every time the Activity is shown.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `invalidateOptionsMenu` whenever you need to change the icon.
It will destroy your menus and re-inflate them by calling `onPrepareOptionsMenu`.